# How to provide transform between costmap frame and robot frame?

Tags: ros, navigation, frame, costmap, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So a costmap_2d [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps) says this:

[image: image description]

My questions are:

Since this is ONE solution, what other ones are there?

And, more specifically, how does *turtlebot_navigation/amcl_demo.launch* provide the transform between the map_file loaded and the turtlebot? (Because **there is no such line** (as in the picture above) in its launch file).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145861/how-to-provide-transform-between-costmap-frame-and-robot-frame?/) by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2014-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any solution that publishes to TF is possible in theory. You can use th API to do that directly from within on of your nodes, you can use URDF+robot_state_publisher, ... I guess the question is really what are you trying to do?

Regarding the amcl demo, the `amcl` node publishes a TF from `odom` to `map` and `base_link` to `map` is provided by the turtlebot driver node, but this is not about costmaps, but rather gridmaps, so not sure where this question is coming from.

**Edit:**

If you are using amcl to localize against a gridmap, you do not need the static_transform_publisher node of the tutorial, as the transform between `base_link` and `map` is provided by your localization module. The static transform node is just very useful for tutorial or testing purposes or in cases where you actually want a static transform (usually the transform between base_link and map changes, unless your robot is not moving).

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-03-31**:
About the first point, nothing specific for now; I was just wondering how else the transform is able to be done for maps :)

And regarding the second, I don't know the difference between costmaps and gridmaps; I thought the map that amcl_demo.launch runs IS a costmap :S

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-31**:
The gridmap is used for laser *localization*. The costmap is used for *navigation*, i.e. local or global path planning an obstacle avoidance. The two are related, but not the same. The gridmap can be a source or layer of the costmap, as the tutorial you linked describes.

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-04-02**:
So, is the gridmap here the same as the grid layer in this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20New%20Layer

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
No, this tutorial is about creating a new type of layer. The gridmap comes into play in the costmap as an existing plugin, namely the costmap_2d::StaticLayer. Look at this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-04-02**:
Right, I went through both tutorials and am confused how to combine the two together. How do I load the layers I created in "Creating a New Layer" onto a costmap via "Configuring Layered Costmaps"?

(Thanks for your time, Sir :)

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
I have not actually tried this myself, but from the Tutorials it seems that you would add your custom layer to the list of plugins in the parameter yaml file, for example with `type: "simple_layer_namespace::SimpleLayer"`.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
Are you actually creating a custom layer, or do you want to add the gridmap as a layer?

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-04-03**:
I am creating a custom layer as per the tutorial i.e. to add a LETHAL_OBSTACLE one meter ahead of the robot. Also, I know how to add my custom layer to the list of plugins, but I do NOT know which "parameter yaml" file to do so in - which one does amcl_demo.launch use? (Isn't gridmap there default?)

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-04**:
I have answered your new question about this. If the currentet question here is answered, please indicate that to others by marking an answer as accepted. Thanks.